# Why does my PhD admission letter include a line about being contingent on satisfying laws?

Tags: graduate-admissions

My PhD letter includes the follow line:

> Note that your offer of admission is contingent upon your satisfaction of all local, state and federal laws.

My question is: I don't have an issue with this contingency per se, but is that standard language to include, or am I being singled out with this line? How can I check whether I was the only one to receive this type of letter.

My concern is that I am being discriminated against. For example, why am I being held in suspicion of possibly breaking any laws, and then my admission should be contingent upon those laws not being broken.

Comment: I am sure this is just a sign that the university's general counsel is a bit keen. I wonder how enforceable this provision actually is - taken literally, this would allow the university to rescind your place for jaywalking or parking in the wrong place. This would seem disproportionate. Maybe one for Law.SE?

Comment: I am perplexed that upon reading that statement, you jump to the conclusion that you might be discriminated against.

Comment: My reading of your question is that you assume they want you to  follow all local laws to the letter. No incorrect parking, no speeding, no misdemeanors, no crimes, in your future or past study. Such reading of that paragraph would be incorrect, they just say you must be legally eligible to study in their country.

Answer (score 44):

If you are a foreign student, your ability to come study in the US depends on your ability to get a visa. If the university makes an admission offer and you later end up being unable to come because of visa (or other immigration-related) issues, you could claim that you were misled by being given an unconditional offer that in the end had to be rescinded because you were unable to physically attend the program. You could even sue the university and ask for damages (people in the US are somewhat fond of suing each other, compared to people in most other countries).

To avoid this situation, universities add language to their offer letters to indicate that the offer is conditioned on applicable laws being satisfied. Immigration issues are the most common type of legal problem that could come up, but the language is a bit more general to make allowance for other sorts of legal obstacles the university has no control over and which could prevent an accepted student from attending.

Bottom line: you are not being discriminated against. This line in admission letters is standard and does not indicate that you (or anyone else whose letter says the same thing) are suspected of having done anything wrong or being in any sort of legal trouble.

Comment: I agree, but also find it a bit sad that universities don't/can't work with applicants to resolve these visa issues early on.

Comment: @Buffy my university has a large office dedicated to helping visiting scholars and students navigate the immigration system. They spend large amounts of resources and attention (at all levels up to and including the university chancellor) on these issues, particularly in special situations that affect large numbers of people (e.g., Trump’s ban on travelers from Muslim countries in 2017, and the pandemic in 2020-21). So I’m not sure what you’re referring to exactly.

Comment: If a legal statement is required to guard against visa issues, the someone, somewhere, has failed to do their job, I think. Not every university is, apparently, as vigilant as the UC system. It is hard to guard against fraud, of course.

Comment: An awful lot of legal statements are written in hopes of never being necessary.  (And perhaps more are written in response to a single incident where such a statement would have come in handy, had it existed at the time...)

Comment: @Buffy I think you are underestimating the extent to which even the most powerful US universities are powerless against national governments. Even with the best of intentions and everyone “doing their job”, it will occasionally happen that someone who is admitted to a US program is refused a visa, or worse, is unjustly [jailed in their home country](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2021/02/08/a-statement-from-mathematics-department-faculty-at-stanford-and-mit/). It’s strange to me that you are interpreting a simple informative statement in an acceptance letter as evidence of negligence.

Comment: @DanRomik I agree in general, but with respect to someone jailed (whether justly or not) in their home country - the boilerplate language does not address that situation at all.  Without further guidance, we can assume that the offer is not contingent upon satisfaction of home country laws.

Comment: @emory sure, good point. I was addressing Buffy’s “sad” sentiment, but you are correct that this is drifting a bit off-topic…

Comment: I don't know what the situation in the US is but in many countries the visa sponsor (i.e. university) have legal liabilities if their sponsee does not comply with the conditions of their visa. I can imagine this sort of language is an attempt to wriggle out of any responsibility.

Comment: @Buffy not even being granted a visa and having the visa sticker in your passport ensures that you will be able to enter the country - the final determination is made by the immigration officer at the port of entry. There is not much the university can do if this immigration officer decides that you are not permitted to enter for whatever reason.

Comment: Somehow you got the idea that I was disagreeing with your answer. I wasn't, in fact. I don't object to the "simple informative statement". Only to the _need_ to write it. And the "objection" is just literally _sadness_, as I said. Please interpret my first comment here literally, as I wrote it.

Comment: I'm also with Dan Romik here initially, but after your latest comment, now I see that what you meant was "It's a bit sad that the reality of this world makes it a possible reality that universities might not be able to work with the candidates to resolve visa issue." Initially I (and I believe Dan Romik too) saw it as "It's a bit sad that universities are bad, they don't want to work with applicants to resolve visa issues." (hence Dan's later reply to yours, about the underestimation) Thanks for clarifying, Buffy!

Comment: @Buffy well okay, thanks for clarifying, but I must admit I still don’t understand who exactly you say is not doing their job, or what is the reason to be sad.

Answer (score 15):

You aren't being discriminated against. It is [boilerplate](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/boilerplate.asp) given to all potential students at this university. There is no suspicion involved, and no singling out.

But the implication is that you agree that if you have lied or misrepresented things in application materials or if, in future, you break some law, then you can be dismissed. It is a kind of "safety clause" that lets the institution easily disassociate itself from any illegal acts.

I don't know how common this is, but it may be increasingly common, perhaps driven by such things as the admissions scandal 2019. If this is the US, there may even be some state law that requires the formulation.

---

When I was a grad student (long ago) we were required to sign "loyalty oaths".

Comment: In addition to Buffy's general answer, *i.e.* law-breaking can get you dismissed, state universities in the United States may be concerned that you are a *bona fide* resident of the state, and some U.S. universities may be concerned that your presence in the U.S. is lawful.

Comment: @BobBrown -indeed, just like a job offer is contingent on having the right to work in the US, international students will need the right visa, and abide by the terms of it.

Comment: I assume the "admissions scandal of a year or so ago" refers to the [Varsity Blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_college_admissions_bribery_scandal) scandal, which was on the news in March 2019, more than two years ago now.

Comment: @Max, yes, that one. Updated. Thanks. Time flies.

Comment: I don't believe this means that you must be in *compliance* with *all* laws, just that you've *satisfied* those relevant to your participation in a graduate program.  Most likely, it's probably an out for visa issues.  Of course, it's vague language, probably intentionally so, to allow the most flexibility when surprises come up.  Picture someone arrested for illegal assembly during a peaceful protest vs someone charged with a hate crime for hanging a noose in a high school.  A univ. might choose to withdraw admission based on the latter and not the former.